# Check and convert float Input Value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Check if a form input is float and round up if that's the case.

I have a form and I want to check if the input is float and round up if that's the case. Why is my code not working?

```
<div class="col-md-12">

<input type="number" id="figure" class="form-control " placeholder="Assign Class Limit" min="1" max="100"/>

</div>

const figure = document.getElementById(figure");

figure.addEventListener("change", (event) =>
if(!isNaN(parseFloat(figure.value))) {

   class_limit = Math.round(event.target.value)}

} else {

   class_limit = event.target.value

}
```

} )

Answer (score 0):

First off, your JavaScript is not enclosed in a script tag. Secondly, your `getElementById` is not properly written, it's missing double quotes at the start of figure.